Git on Visual Studio shows .js files(not changed) in change section after build project everytime
I am using Visual Studio 2022, Although there is no changes on .js files, When I build project , the files are displayed in GitChnages--> Changes section , when  I compare with unmodified version of files, no changes can be observerd. Everytime I  build/rebuild project, I am facing this issue. Is there a way to get rid of this erroneous behavior?


There are changes. Git check the content of files so if it founds a modification, contents are different and you should understand why. Check if it's not just a matter of end of line or file encoding (Notepad++ is better than VS to help find this type of issues). In this case, you will have to use a .gitattributes file to handle that and/or configure your editor to save with good eol char (with .editorconfig file).

I agree with @Philippe that the reason you're seeing this is most likely due to whitespace differences from the generated version and the tracked version in Git. Something to consider is whether these files should even be tracked in the first place...

somehow I can not fix,I committed all changes(in fact there was no change) and then after that I will not have the issue. It might have happened because other developer was working with Visual studio code and I am working with classical VS but I am not sure
